# Alternative PS3 Controller for bigger Hands

Tags: ps3, controllers

My hands hurt when I am using the ps3 controller for longer than one hour. It is too small for my hands. Are there good alternative controllers I can use that are a little bit bigger? The xbox controller fits perfectly and I never have any problems when playing on a xbox.

Comment: This seems like a shopping recommendation to me (offtopic).

Answer (score 2):

Power A offers a controller that has the same configuration and larger size of an Xbox 360 controller, the [Pro Elite Wireless Controller](http://www.powera.com/ps3/ps3.asp?section=5&prod=051083). It does have a bunch of varying reviews on Amazon however, and I have no experience with it so I can't recommend it either way.
[image]

Comment: It's not necessary that the controller has the same configuration as the xbox controller. The most important factor is the size. Can anybody actually recommend a controller that he/she is using?

Comment: Understood, it also is larger and similar in size to the 360 controller, so fits that need.